# Is it possible to interpolate angular library components with project data?

Tags: angular, interpolation, libraries

I'm working on creating a custom Angular Component Library and I've been running into an issue. I create a component within my library that contains interpolated data. Within that component's .ts file I declare the variable but only assign a type as I don't want a default value. (Example: {{myVar}} myVar:string;}

In the actual project that I import the library, I include my library component in the app.component.html and within app.component.ts I redefine that same variable but this time with a value. (Example: myVar: string = "My actual data"). However this doesn't appear when rendering the page. I'm assuming because the library component is still looking at the .ts file within the library for the value. Is this a correct assumption? If so, is there any way to interpolate components within a library with data from a project that is importing it?

Thank you.

Comment: Angular expressions in a template are always evaluated against their component instance. They will never, ever get values from other components. This is fundamental stuff. Creating a reusable component library is quite an advanced, complex topic. You should first practice on simple applications, because this is fundamental stuff that you need to understand first.

Answer (score 0):

Thr best way to do that by using Directive & Input Decorator.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataResolved">
.....
```

---

```
@Input() dataResolved: DataResolvedDirective;
```

---

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dataResolved]'
})
export class DataResolvedDirective{

  constructor( httpClient: HttpClient ) { // OR DI - Existing Service
    }
  @Input() set dataResolved( ) {
        return this.httpClient.get('remote server url + uri');
    }
```